# Add Player in Wordpress Blog Homepage, Not Just the Post Page

Tags: wordpress, audio, media-player, blogs, mediaelement.js

I have a Wordpress blog setup now and the media player is displaying properly in posts. However, on the homepage, it is only showing me a link to the blog.

How can I add the player to the homepage as well?

Thank you for the help, I'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

First please check your current activated homepage from wp-admin>>setting>>Reading>>Front page displays .If it is Your latest posts then you can code for it by editing index.php page of your current theme. And if you don't know about php that much then you can choose any static page from backend and use shortcode of player in that